# Linq2DB doesn't translate a computation expression inside select statement

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, linq2db

I'm using Linq2DB over EF Core database context, which is connected to the PostgreSQL 15, and I want to generate a query that will have complex calculations inside the `SELECT` statement.

##### Environment

Packages:

- Linq2DB.EntityFrameworkCore 7.3.0
- Linq2DB 5.1.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.4
- Npgsql 7.0.2
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 7.0.3

A piece of configuration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DtDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        var dbOptions = new DbOptions();
        builder.Configuration.Bind(nameof(DbOptions), dbOptions);
        var connectionString = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Username = dbOptions.User,
            Password = dbOptions.Secret,
            Host = dbOptions.Host,
            Database = dbOptions.Database,
        }.ToString(); 
        options
            .EnableDetailedErrors(true)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
            .UseNpgsql(connectionString)
            .UseLinqToDB(
                innerOptions =>
                {
                    innerOptions.AddCustomOptions(o => o
                        .UsePostgreSQL(connectionString, PostgreSQLVersion.v15)
                        .UseTraceLevel(TraceLevel.Verbose)
                        .UseTracing(static info => Console.WriteLine(info.SqlText)));
                });
    });
```

##### Intro

I have an entity defined like this:

```cs
public class Entry
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Ts { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Tt { get; set; }
    public string RecSrc { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

To get my data, I need to use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(srcBrn."Id", srcDef."Id") AS "Id",
    CASE
        WHEN srcDef."Ts" > COALESCE(srcBrn."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcDef."Ts"
        WHEN srcBrn."Ts" >= COALESCE(srcDef."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcBrn."Ts"
        ELSE '2000-01-01'
    END AS "Ts",
    CASE
        WHEN srcDef."Ts" > COALESCE(srcBrn."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcDef."Tt"
        WHEN srcBrn."Ts" >= COALESCE(srcDef."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcBrn."Tt"
        ELSE NULL
    END AS "Tt",
    CASE
        WHEN srcDef."Ts" > COALESCE(srcBrn."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcDef."RecSrc"
        WHEN srcBrn."Ts" >= COALESCE(srcDef."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcBrn."RecSrc"
        ELSE NULL
    END AS "RecSrc",
    CASE
        WHEN srcDef."Ts" > COALESCE(srcBrn."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcDef."Value"
        WHEN srcBrn."Ts" >= COALESCE(srcDef."Ts", '2000-01-01') THEN srcBrn."Value"
        ELSE 0
    END AS "Value"
FROM (SELECT * FROM "Entry" WHERE "RecSrc" = 'default') srcDef
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM "Entry" WHERE "RecSrc" = 'branch') srcBrn
    ON srcBrn."Id" = srcDef."Id"
```

To build such a query, I've made the following LINQ code:

```cs
var sourceDefault = _db.Set<Entry>()
    .Where(e => e.RecSrc == "default");
var sourceBranch = _db.Set<Entry>()
    .Where(e => e.RecSrc == "branch");

q = from srcDef in sourceDefault
    from srcBrn in sourceBranch.FullJoin(eBr => eBr.Id == srcDef.Id)
    select new Entry
    {
        Id = (Guid?) srcBrn.Id ?? srcDef.Id,
        Ts = srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.Ts
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.Ts
                : DateTime.MinValue,
        Tt = srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.Tt
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.Tt
                : null,
        RecSrc = srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.RecSrc
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.RecSrc
                : null,
        Value = srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.Value
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.Value
                : 0,
    };
```

##### Problem

The entire SQL made by Linq2DB translator looks similar to what I need. However, the `SELECT` statement of a generated SQL just contains all columns from both joined tables rather than expressions as was expected:

```sql
SELECT
    Coalesce(t1."Id", "srcDef"."Id"),
    "srcDef"."Ts",
    Coalesce(t1."Ts", :MinValue_1),
    t1."Ts",
    Coalesce("srcDef"."Ts", :MinValue_1),
    "srcDef"."Tt",
    t1."Tt",
    "srcDef"."RecSrc",
    t1."RecSrc",
    "srcDef"."Value_1",
    t1."Value_1"
FROM (
    SELECT
        e."Id",
        e."Ts",
        e."Tt",
        e."RecSrc",
        e."Value" as "Value_1"
    FROM
        "Entry" e
    WHERE
        e."RecSrc" = 'default'
) "srcDef"
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT
        e_1."Id",
        e_1."Ts",
        e_1."Tt",
        e_1."RecSrc",
        e_1."Value" as "Value_1"
    FROM
        "Entry" e_1
    WHERE
        e_1."RecSrc" = 'branch'
) t1 ON t1."Id" = "srcDef"."Id"
```

It looks like Linq2DB computes column values on client side.

We can suppose that Linq2DB just can't translate such a complex expression into a proper SQL. However, it is not true and it is easy to check.

Let's add `.OrderBy(e => e.Value)` to the LINQ expression:

As expected, translator will add the `ORDER BY` statement to the end of generated SQL, and with successfully translated `Value` column calculation expression:

```sql
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN "srcDef"."Ts" > Coalesce(t1."Ts", :MinValue_1) THEN "srcDef"."Value_1"
        WHEN t1."Ts" >= Coalesce("srcDef"."Ts", :MinValue_1) THEN t1."Value_1"
        ELSE 0
    END;
```

Therefore it is clear that Linq2DB translator can translate complex expressions and even use it here and there.

I've tried to use `.AsSubQuery()`, but no effect -- it just wraps the query above and keeps all redundant columns.

Client-side computation means that 2 times more data will be downloaded. I don't want to use raw SQL.

##### Question

Is there any chance to force Linq2DB to generate `SELECT` statement with fields computation like shown in the very beginning of this description? Any setting? What am I missed?

Comment: I think it's the `DateTime.MinValue`  that's confusing it. Try pass that value in as a parameter. Also maybe try `Value = (srcDef.Ts > srcBrn.Ts || srcBrn.Ts == null) ? srcDef.Value : ((srcBrn.Ts >= srcDef.Ts || srcDef.Ts == null) ? srcBrn.Value : 0)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems we met some kind of optimisation here. The `Sql.AsSql` function helps in this case. It must be used in each place we don't need this optimisation.

```cs
var sourceDefault = _db.Set<Entry>()
    .Where(e => e.RecSrc == Consts.RecSrc.Default);
var sourceBranch = _db.Set<Entry>()
    .Where(e => e.RecSrc == Consts.RecSrc.Branch);

q = from srcDef in sourceDefault
    from srcBrn in sourceBranch.FullJoin(eBr => eBr.Id == srcDef.Id)
    select new Entry
    {
        Id = (Guid?) srcBrn.Id ?? srcDef.Id,
        Ts = Sql.AsSql(srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.Ts
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.Ts
                : DateTime.MinValue),
        Tt = Sql.AsSql(srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.Tt
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.Tt
                : null),
        RecSrc = Sql.AsSql(srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.RecSrc
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.RecSrc
                : null),
        Value = Sql.AsSql(srcDef.Ts > ((DateTime?) srcBrn.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
            ? srcDef.Value
            : srcBrn.Ts >= ((DateTime?) srcDef.Ts ?? DateTime.MinValue)
                ? srcBrn.Value
                : 0),
    };
```

However, it is still not clear how to disable this at all.

Comment: Right solution at the moment. Should be solved in linq2db 6.